Building a Chatbot Using RAG and Llama3 for Custom Table Database
I’m working on a project to create a chatbot using Retrieval-Augmented Generation (RAG) with Llama3 (1B model). The chatbot needs to interact with a custom database that is structured in table format. The database contains details about products, including:
Product ID
Product Name
Price
Number in Stock
Features
Last Updated Date
And more...
The goal is to allow users to ask natural language queries like:
“What is the price of Product X?”
“Show me all products under $100.”
“Which products were updated recently?”
I’m trying to figure out the best approach to implement this. Specifically:
How can I integrate Llama3 with a retrieval mechanism for the database?
Should I preprocess the table into embeddings for faster retrieval, or rely on real-time SQL queries?
Are there any open-source libraries or frameworks to simplify building RAG-based chatbots?
Any tips for ensuring the chatbot can handle filtering, sorting, or aggregating data dynamically?
Any advice, examples, or resources you could share would be a huge help! Thanks in advance. :)

You can use Langchain for building a RAG + Text to SQL LLM chat bot. Please see this Langchain tutorial.
